# Azure AD Exceeding Reply URL Limit

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am an admin for my company's Azure AD Subscription. I have someone who has reached Azure's limit of 10 Reply URLs in their app configuration. I am wondering what options do they have for adding more Reply URLs. They explain:

> We are a team that will onboard multiple partners/domains
>   to our platform. Each of these partners will require Azure AD
>   authentication and will have different Reply URLs.

I imagine that support for more Reply URLs will come in the next version of Azure AD. What options can I present to this team in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the classic portal, you can upload the Application Manifest with more than 10 Reply URLs. The classic portal UI will show errors but the Reply URLs do hold.

In the new "Ibiza" portal, the Reply URL limit has been removed. You can intuitively add more than 10 Reply URLs.

Answer (score 1):

In new portal 'ibiza' you can add 256 reply urls.
I don't think in any case, the customer is going to exceed this limit, unless they haven't configured their architecture wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would create a different tenant for each partner you onboard (multi-tenancy) and recreate the application with client specific reply URL there. Are you using Azure AD or Azure AD B2B?

A somewhat nasty alternative is to set up another identity solution such as IdentityServer3 and have that use AzureAd as an IdP. Then load the tons of reply URLs into IdentityServer3.